# How do we choose appropriate moment conditions for GMM estimation?

Tags: econometrics, applied-econometrics, industrial-organisation, gmm

In certain conditions, especially with just-identified models, the appropriate moment conditions are in some sense obvious. This is the case, for instance, when we recover parameters from the linear model $Y = X\beta + \epsilon $ using the moment condition $\mathbb{E}[X_i(y_i - X_i^T\beta)] = 0$, derived from the assumption that $\mathbb{E}[\epsilon_i \mid X_i ] = 0$ at only the true $\beta$.

Conversely, consider the setting of [Berry (1992)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2951571), where we have $T$ independent markets and $K$ potential entrants in each market, and some market and firm-by-market level characteristics given by $x_t$ and $z_{kt}$ respectively. We observe data on which firms actually enter, denoted $I_{kt}$ and can theoretically predict the probability of a given firm $k$ entering a market $t$ by solving for a subgame perfect equilibrium in a sequential entry game. This allows us to create a function $\hat{P}_{kt}(x_t, \mathbf{z_t}, \theta)$ which is the theoretical probability, and where $\theta$ is a vector of $ p < K$ parameters from the payoff function. We can then write $$ I_{kt} = \hat{P}_{kt}(x_t, \mathbf{z_t}, \theta) + \xi_{kt} $$ and we assume that $$ \mathbb{E}[\xi_{kt} \mid x_t, z_{kt}] = 0 \ \forall k \in \{1,\ldots,K\}. $$

This implies the following general class of moment conditions that set
$$ \mathbb{E}\left[(I_{kt} - \hat{P}_{kt}(x_t, \mathbf{z_t}, \theta))f(z_{kt},x_t) \right] = 0$$ for any Borel function $f$.

What is the best choice of $f$ for the estimator? The identification condition is assumed to hold for any choice of $f$ so we have consistency and asymptotic normality under the usual regularity conditions. What is unclear to me then, is how the choice of $f$ affects rates of convergence, and efficiency, if at all, of the estimator. My naive guess is that continuous and bijective functions $f$ work best, since they preserve information (I may be wrong, but I think that $\sigma(f(X)) = \sigma(X)$ for such functions). Of course, such functions burden us with $2K$ moment conditions rather than just $K$, since there’s no continuous bijection from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}$. Is there any sense in which some functions work best, or some work better than others?